# Can a Russian apply for European visa twice if he didn't go to the countries he applied to in the first?

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, portugal, russian-citizens

My girlfriend applied for a **1 year Italian visa** because they had already given it to her before for some weeks so now they would give her the whole year.

What ended up happening is that life got in the way and **we ended up not going to Italy**, but going to several other European countries (specially Portugal, where I'm from).

She is very **worried that she will have difficulties applying for European Visa again**. 
Should she be? What's the worst case scenario and how can it be remedied?

Comment: Has your gf already submitted the application?  Also, your title says 'he', but the question says 'she'.

Comment: She.. Typo.. Is there a difference? No, not yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your gf did not report her variance to the Italian consulate, and did not enter Italy first (or spend the majority of her visit in Italy), then her next application is imperilled, but not necessarily a de facto refusal.

For cases like this, they are *entitled* to use Refusal Grounds # 8...

> ...the information submitted regarding the justification for the
>   purpose of the intended stay was not reliable...

what that basically says is that they do not trust her based upon her performance.

Of course it's not an automatic refusal and the net has countless anecdotes where people applied successfully.

So the answers to your questions are...  yes, she should be concerned.  The worst case scenario is a refusal on #8.

And for your last question, how can it be remedied...  the answer is to get more visas from countries that monitor performance like the USA, Canada, the UK, and so on.  They love to see histories like that.

Comment: Is it different if you don't use the visa at all? And is it different for electronic travel authorisation systems like ESTA, eTA, ETIAS or eVisitor (the latter technically being an Australian visa)?